# codeigniter my page correctly displays but header says 404 error

Tags: codeigniter, session, header

I'm trying to track down why my form's post data isn't being passed to the controller.

When I go to the controller's url, the page displays properly.  But when I open up firebug it says theres a 404 error.

I'm stumped. How can there be a 404 error when the page is being displayed?

I've checked and double-checked everything.  I don't know why this is happening.

UPDATE:  This same thing is happening on all my controller's url's.  When I visit the site, the page displays just fine, but firebug says 404.  I just didn't realize it until now because the other pages aren't accepting any post data.

On the members page, if they're not logged in it redirects.  Here, firebug says 302 temporarily moved, which is what it's supposed to do.  But when I'm logged in and visit the members page it's 404.

I suspect I need to alter the config->router.php file, but I'm not sure how it needs modified.

Comment: It might help to add your file structure. Also, whenever I used codeigniter I never needed to manually add routes - things just automagically worked.

Comment: I have a controller named foobar.php and access it's index function via site.com/foobar/  I'm not quite sure what to say about my file structure; views are in the views folder, models in the model folder, etc.  I havn't made any changes to the routes.

Answer (score 0):

In case that link changes, heres the instructions on that page that I followed to get everything working properly:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Godaddy-Installaton-Tips

In config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php?";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "QUERY_STRING";
```

I've successfully implemented this on GoDaddy without using "index.php?" as the index page. This is helpful when using anchor() in the URL helper to create links. Even with htaccess removing the index.php, anchor() will still put in what you have set as an index page.

You should now be able to access everything as such:

http://yourdomain.com/index.php?controller/action/etc

Once you get to a point where you want to hide the 'index.php?' paste this into your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

You should now be able to access everything as such:

http://yourdomain.com/controller/action/etc

The .htaccess file must be in Unix LF only style. If you use Notepad or Wordpad and upload an .htaccess file in CR/LF style it won't work.